# How do I increase the size of live image [aufs]?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, tmpfs

When I boot into a live image to try out ubuntu, the core storage capacity is 50% of the memory that I have available.

> aufs             16G  6.2G  9.6G  40% / [32GB total]

How do I increase the size of this?

Arch Linux seems to have feasible solutions available for this: https://www.ostechnix.com/adjust-size-root-partition-live-arch-linux/ and https://superuser.com/questions/753134/how-to-adjust-the-size-of-the-root-partition-on-live-arch-linux-system-dev-ma

However, neither of the methods work for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

### `casper-rw` partition, that is big enough

One way to increase the size of the live image is to create a persistent live drive with a `casper-rw` partition, that is big enough.

The size of **`aufs`** or the corresponding **`cow`** in some versions will match the size of the `casper-rw` partition. For example in a persistent live drive with 32 GB you can have close to that, approximately 30 GB, for `aufs` or `cow` (some drive space will be used for other data), if you select all available drive space, 100%, for persistence.

**mkusb** can create a persistent live drive with a `casper-rw` partition and prepare 'everything' on the drive for it to work. This works in all current Ubuntu versions and community flavours and corresponding iso files.

See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

The end of mkusb's output to its console:

```
...
parted -s "/dev/sdc" print
Model: SanDisk Extreme (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 32,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 2      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               primary  bios_grub
 3      2097kB  258MB   256MB   fat32        primary  boot, esp
 4      258MB   2199MB  1941MB               primary
 5      2199MB  32,0GB  29,8GB  ext2         primary
 1      32,0GB  32,0GB  1031kB               primary  msftdata

lsblk -o MODEL,NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE "/dev/sdc"
MODEL            NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                  MOUNTPOINT    SIZE
Extreme          sdc                                                29,8G
                 |-sdc1                                           1006,5K
                 |-sdc2                                                1M
                 |-sdc3 vfat    usbboot                              244M
                 |-sdc4 iso9660 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64               1,8G
                 `-sdc5 ext4    casper-rw                           27,8G
</pre>
 Done :-) 
The target device is ready to use.
'ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
was installed
item 100
Cleanup after dus-persistent finished :-)
```

Screenshot from the running persistent live system with 30 GB for `cow`:

[image]